# Powershell: given a string, how can I tell what type of path I am dealing with?

Tags: powershell

For instance, I can type `gci hkcu:` and get a list of registry entries back, or I could type `gci c:\` and get a directory listing.

Assuming `$list` holds the result of one of these queries, how can I tell what I'm dealing with?

I could, of course, just perform something like `$list[0].GetType()` and parse the result, but that's not very robust, and besides, what would I do with an empty list? (Which means I'm probably asking the wrong question, since I think I need to know the answer before I actually call `gci`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While trying to code around the issue, I stumbled upon the answer:

`(Get-ItemProperty $path).PSProvider.Name`

This will return one of the providers listed in `Get-PSProvider`, and they are (typically) unchanging.

Comment: Assuming $list holds the result of one of these queries: @($list)[0].PSProvider.Name

Answer (score 3):

You can do the below maybe:

```
 $path = "HKCU:"
 $qualifier = (split-path $path -Qualifier).Trim(":")
 get-psdrive | ?{ $_.Name -eq $qualifier } | select provider
```

If the path is relative use `resolve-path $path`

Also you don't have to use `gci` on the path. you can just use `gi`:

```
(gi hkcu:).gettype()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to handle what is passed into gci, rather than attempting to handle the output. Then all you have to do is look before the `:`, or worst case check the "local" directory.

Comment: One issue with this is that this won't work for the following: `cd hkcu:; gci`.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I didn't grok your "worst case" line right away.